# Why is my Java Program returning only the last String in an ArrayList

Tags: java

I want my Java Program to return a String response based on if/else conditions but it only responds to the last element in the ArrayList.
I have been working on this for two days without success. 
I will appreciate a direction as to what am doing wrongly. Thank You

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ScanUtility implements IScanUtility { 

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("ScanUtility"); 


    private  String performHostScan(String nodeName) {   

         Process OSCmdProcess = null; 
         Integer exitValue = null;
         String OScmd = null;
         String exitMessage = null;

        String OScmd = new String("/usr/bin/ssh ansible@" + nodeName + " " + "/tmp/openscapscan.bash rheldisa"); 

        try {
            OSCmdProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(OScmd);
             exitValue = OSCmdProcess.waitFor(); 
            if (exitValue.equals(0)) {  

                exitMessage = ("Succeeded on" + " " + nodeName);
                return exitMessage; 
              } else {
                  exitMessage =  ("Failed on" + " " + nodeName);
                return exitMessage;
            }
        } catch (IOException ioExcep) {
            ioExcep.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException interExcep) {
            interExcep.printStackTrace();
        }
        return exitMessage;

    }  



       //This method takes an ArrayList of hosts from the servlet controller
      // and passes the list to the ScanUtility Method above
      //============================================================
     public String generateHostName(List<String>  addressList){  
           String statusMessage = null;
          for(String nodeName: addressList){         
              statusMessage =  new ScanUtility().performHostScan(nodeName);
          }
        return statusMessage;                 
      }
}
```

Comment: You are overriding `statusMessage` in each of your steps in the for loop. Maybe you want to return a `List<String>` instead of a single String?

Comment: `for(String nodeName: addressList){statusMessage =  new canUtility().performHostScan(nodeName);}` Take a deep into this part.

Comment: Also it is hard to understand how the logic inside `performHostScan` could effect what to return from `generateHostName`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are overwriting `statusMessage` on ever iteration of your loop. I believe what you want to do is put all the Strings into an `ArrayList<String>`.

```
 public ArrayList<String> generateHostName(List<String>  addressList){  
      ArrayList<String> statusMessage = new ArrayList<>();
      for(String nodeName: addressList){         
          statusMessage.add(new ScanUtility().performHostScan(nodeName));
      }
      return statusMessage;                 
  }
```

Comment: You probably want to change the return type of that method so that your code compiles

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks for pointing that out! Edited accordingly

Comment: The code compiles, it's just that it returns  the message for only the last element that is scanned

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you want to return **a list of status messages** (a status message from each server that you are scanning).

```
public List<String> getResponsesFromAddresses(List<String> addresses) {
    final ScanUtility scanUtility = new ScanUtility();

    return addresses.stream()
                     .map(scanUtility::performHostScan)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The method name is misleading. I have changed it to `getResponsesFromAddresses` - that is what the method actually does.

Comment: Thank You so much!!. You guys are awesome! It worked:  Vulnerability Scan Succeeded on eagle
Vulnerability Scan Succeeded on falcon
Vulnerability Scan Succeeded on hawk
Vulnerability Scan Succeeded on owl
Vulnerability Scan Succeeded on osprey

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  public List<String> generateHostName(List<String>  addressList){  
      List<String> statusMessages = new ArrayList<>();
      for(String nodeName: addressList){         
          statusMessages.add(new ScanUtility().performHostScan(nodeName));
      }
      return statusMessages;                 
  }
```

Comment: It Worked !. Thanks a million   Vulnerability Scan Succeeded on eagle
Vulnerability Scan Succeeded on falcon
Vulnerability Scan Succeeded on hawk
Vulnerability Scan Succeeded on owl
Vulnerability Scan Succeeded on osprey